# What are fixed format files and how is XML better than them?

Tags: xml

I searched google for fixed format file (FFF) and got these to results:

- [pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/fixed-file.htm](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/fixed-file.htm)
- [www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS%5CFeatures%5CFixed-Width-Text-File-Definition.htm](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS%5CFeatures%5CFixed-Width-Text-File-Definition.htm)

I am not sure which one is a fixed format file. Is the second one FFF or its something else ?

What problems did FFF solve and how does XML solve them better than FFF ?
Are there any disadvantages of XML format when compared to FFF ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest advantage of a FFF over XML is built-in capability of index-based random-access. The contra-positive is obvious, the biggest *disadvantage* of XML compared to FFF is the linear fashion in which it must be parsed.

Suppose you have a data file holding person records. The records can hold an id, name, address, and telephone number.

**Fixed Format**

```
ID          : 8 chars
Surname     : 36 chars
Firstname   : 36 chars
Address     : 100 chars
Phone       : 20 chars
-----------------------
Total Space: 200 chars
```

**XML Format** (contrived, could be a number of formats)

```
<Person id="...">
   <Surname>...</>
   <Firstname>...</>
   <Address>...</>
   <Phone>...</>
</Person>

Total Space : Variant
```

Now, suppose this has 1000 "records" Lets see how difficult it is to get to the 600th person record with both forms.

**Fixed Format**

```
Offset = (600-1)*200 = 119800 bytes
fseek() + fread() = done
```

**XML Format**

```
Um.....
```

**XML's biggest forte is extensibility** (that **X** didn't come from nothing).  XML makes a fantastic data-snippet, RSS feed, configuration file, etc. It is easy to emit without special libraries and only basic knowhow, and can be reasonable in storage space (so long as you don't go `<LoveThoseSuperDuperLongElementNames>` nuts). It is easy to understand, backed by boatloads of standards, and just about everyone that's anyone has an XML parser in their toolkit. Universal "understanding" is just a schema document (DTD for the old-schoolers) away, as is validation, etc.

But XML's biggest downside has been, is now, and until quantum computing leaps a long way, always will be: **speed**. XML is a **terrible** throughput-mandated storage system.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig. I appreciate it.
Is there a book for that discusses such things ?

Comment: Eh. not particularly that i've read. My views on XML vs. FFF are more practice than study. Each has a solid and firm place in the industry, of that I have no doubt. Each is a tool, and like all tools they're designed for specific purposes. Just think about what you *need* and what you *want* when designing your solutions to choose the best tool that fits.

Comment: I had one more doubt - 
Is are FFF also called "Fixed Width Text File" ? Or flat file database ? I need to be sure so that I can use the right word for my google searches. 

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed File Format (sometimes called a Flat File Format), Fixed-Width Format, and a surrey of other terms that all generally mean one thing: an entity size (record, field, etc) is *known* ahead of time, and is a fixed size. It is that fixed size, especially when optimized against the native storage allocation size of the media being managed (disk files generally) that grants performance boost by effectively allowing you to to treat your file like a virtual "array".

Comment: I see that your fields have variable lengths, but the overall record (for a person) has a fixed size. I saw an example by IBM, which says that all fields should be of fixed length. Is that compulsory ?
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r1mx/topic/com.ibm.wbit.610.help.config.doc/topics/rfixwidth.html

Comment: @XMLBoy Yes. The content therein can be variant, but is 'filled' with sentinel non-data. String data representation is the real variant. A 'name' field that can be 36 chars long may only actually be 2 ('Al'). The remaining space for that field is unused *for that record*, but that is the price you pay for the speed-of-access for fixed-width format. Funny you should mention IBM. Their highest scaling platform for databases, zSeries OS/390, is a database management system implemented in *hardware* with the OS sitting on top, and it uses fixed-width data as a cornerstone for performance.

Comment: Thanks. I also think that I did not explain myself correctly. You said that ID is 8 chars, Surname is 36 chars etc. Is this the maximum length of the respective fields or is it the length of the data actually entered in the fields. IBM said that the max length of all fields should be the same. Just wanted to know if both are okay.

Comment: @XMLBoy All fields *are* fixed length in the sample I showed,l Just not the *same* length per field. But each record, as you see, is fixed in overall length. That is where the performance boasts.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're comparing with XML, I'm assuming you mean a fixed width text file (the latter of your examples). Saying which is "better" isn't easy, it very much depends on your use case.

Some advantages of XML;

- Flexible (ie fields can be longer/shorter or may even be added without breaking existing code)
- There are many implementations to choose from.
- You can define it more or less fully using machine readable schemas.
  (that means a computer can generate code to read and validate the file to some extent if you just have a schema defining the file)

Some advantages to fixed width files;

- *Much* simpler, both reading and writing a file is more or less trivial.
- May take less space, XML is rather "chatty".

Comment: I had one more doubt - Is are FFF also called "Fixed Width Text File" ? Or flat file database ? I need to be sure so that I can use the right word for my google searches. Thanks.